# Eclipse: Change specific Keys/actions that choose the selected suggestion when content assist is open

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

This was wrongly flagged as a duplicate, so I can't answer. I found a solution: Since version 2018-12 there's the option to disable all insertion triggers except enter (under Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist). This is exactly what i wanted

Using java content assist, I sometimes come across certain cases where the popup with suggestions opens itself but I just want to keep typing.

However, since typing space or `(` for some reason takes the currently selected suggestion and closes the popup, I sometimes end up having to delete the inserted suggestion by hand which takes some time.

Is there some way I can configure that I do not want space or `(` to select the suggestion but instead just type in the character, effectively closing the content assist popup? If not, are there plugins for this?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Clarification why this is not a duplicate: CTRL + Space are opening content assist for me. That is not the problem.

My problem is what actually completes the suggestion from content assist. E.g. suppose I have logger utility with a method called `log(param1, param2, param3, ...);` with 7 parameters and a method `log(param1);` with 1 parameter.

I have contest assist enabled on `.` presses so if I type `this.log` the content assist popup will be open and prompting me with `log(7 parameters)` and `log(1 parameter)`.

If I typed too fast and didn't realize content assist opening, and now type a `(` after the `this.log`, the content assist will automatically choose the first suggestion with 7 parameters for me and insert it into my code, instead of just letting me type the `(`

I want to know if I can disable that space, `(` or `;` insert the suggestion from content assist. Is there a setting or a plugin e.g. for enabling only Enter to fill in the suggestion?

Comment: I now clarified why my question is not a duplicate. I hope now people understand what my problem is about. @yash

Answer (score 0):

Open up Eclipse, in the top bar to the right click on "Window".
Then, click "Preferences" (should be at the bottom)
A window should pop up and type in the tool bar "typing".
There should be a left side bar, click on Typing, located under Java 
and you should be able to uncheck whatever auto assist you desire.

Comment: There are some options for turning of auto completion of e.g. parentheses. I can't find keys associated with content assist? Is there something I'm missing? Can you disable space for selecting content assist results from the page you gave me?